# app-only authentication - AcquireTokenForClient not returning token

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0

Trying to authenticate an EWS appliation using OAuth app-only authentication. When trying to retrieve the token ("var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();") program exits with code 0. Doesn't throw any errors.

AcquireTokenForClient - not returning any token.

Followed below documentation. Implemented exactly as mentioned in this documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

Please let me know if I'm missing anything

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am having this problem too. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Hi @Sundeep, please share your code so we can see your implementation and probably show you where the issue is.